# Java Generics lower bound and assigning a function to a subtype

Tags: java, generics

Confused on this one (The error is on assigning `f2 = func1`).

1. Why is creating func1 not an error as we are using Number.shortValue() but defined a lower bound as a Number?
2. If `func1` can be created this way then why cannot it be assigned to `f2`?

Thanks for your help.

```
    Function<? super Number, ? extends String> func1 = obj -> String.valueOf(obj.shortValue());
    Function<Integer, String> f2 = func1;
```

The error is:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.function.Function<capture<? super java.lang.Number>,capture<? extends java.lang.String>>', required: 'java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>'
```

Comment: Because func1's type is not compatible with f2's

Comment: `? super Number` means any class that is `Number` or a **super** class of it, i.e. `Object`. What you want ist `? extends Number` to instantiate **sub** classes, i.e. `Integer`.

Comment: Look at this question for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: @Sascha no: `Function<? extends Number, ...>` is a `Function` that accepts a specific but unknown subclass of `Number`. You wouldn't be able to pass anything into such a `Function` except for literal `null`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Function<? super Number, ? extends String> func1 = obj -> String.valueOf(obj.shortValue());
> ```
>
> 1. Why is creating func1 not an error as we are using Number.shortValue() but defined a lower bound as a Number?

The right-hand side of this assignment is a `Function<Number, String>`. You're allowed to assign that to a variable of type `Function<? super Number, ? extends String>` because that's a more general type; but you won't be able to pass anything into it which isn't a `Number` (or literal `null`), and so anything you are allowed to pass to it will have a `shortValue()` method.

`Function<? super Number, ...>` means "a Function that it's safe to pass a `Number` to; it's *not* "a Function that you can pass any superclass of `Number` to".

> ```
> Function<Integer, String> f2 = func1;
> ```
>
> 2. If func1 can be created this way then why cannot it be assigned to f2?

As I stated above, a `Function<Number, String>` is a `Function<? super Number, ? extends String>`; the converse is not true.

It's the same as "all apples are fruit; not all fruit are apples".

Comment: I thought I understood type inference and type parameter bounds pretty well, but I guess I never before saw a lower bound factor into type inference in this way.  It feels wrong that the inferred type is not `Function<Object, String>`, leading to an error on account of `Object` not having a `shortValue()` method.

Comment: That was my confusion also